# Filter out certain numbers from the 7th position

Tags: 2010, list-view, column

I need to filter out the items in a list that contain numbers 5,6,7 if they are in the 7th position within the tracking number.  I know you can do this in Excel, but can you do this in a workflow or through a calculated column?

I really would want If Tracking Number contains 5,6,7 than update Use column to Yes.  I know this is confusing. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a Yes/No calculated field with the following formula.

```
=IF(OR(MID(Title,7,1)="7",MID(Title,7,1)="6",MID(Title,7,1)="5"),"Yes","No")
```

Just change "Title" to your Tracking Number field.

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you so much!!  You saved me a lot of time!  Thank you thank you thank you!!

Comment: Now working on another column. What if I need a contains command instead of an = ?

Comment: So contains 5,6,7 but doesn't need to be in the 7th position?